# How to get mirrored tiling in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv

I'm trying to make a texture tiling mirrored as you can do in Internal. It seems that it's not so easy in Cycles. I want this:

[image]

Note that besides the A1 square you can see the same square mirrored, as well as in the G8 one and any other square in the texture's limit.

Is there any way to achieve this in Cycles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update December 2022**

In Blender 3.5, the Image Texture node has a new mirror extension type (see [here](https://developer.blender.org/D16432)). So you can finally just set the Texture node to "Mirror".

[image: Image Texture node with set to Mirror]

Answer (score 11):

You can achieve this usign math nodes:
<sub>Click for full size</sub>
[image: nodes]

**Edit:**
I have just seen you can even leave out the modulo operation. I thought it would make the coordinates repeat between 0 and 1 but it just does nothing.

[Here](http://pasteall.org/blend/33902) is the .blend file for you.

What this node setup does is basically flip the UV coordinates when the image border is reached.

Result (with multiple flips):

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly, even better than Internal! :D Just a little more question, how you can even made that node setup from scratch? It's crazy :P

Comment: Well, I just thought about what happens to the texture coordinates and translated that to math nodes ;)
And I had to solve similar problems for an image processing lecture, so I already had a rough structure for the calculations in my head.

Comment: @AntonioBuch recommend you watch: http://cgcookie.com/blender/cgc-courses/custom-uv-transformation-nodes-cycles/ to understand all the math :)

Comment: I'd also recommend watching this talk from the blender conference: http://youtu.be/kAUmLcXhUj0

Comment: That's awesome, but took me a while to notice that the second input of the power node is used instead of the first. Also your .blend file is no longer available. Try the blender stack exchange [dedicated server](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).

Answer (score 11):

Blender 2.82 added a new Pingpong mode to the Math node, which simplifies maddin45's answer. Make sure to set the scale on the Pingpong nodes to 1.0.

[image: Mirrored tiling setup using Pingpong nodes]

Comment: Is there a way to make this apply to the UVs *after* they've been affected by a UV Warp modifier?

Comment: @ArrowCase The UVs coming out of the UV Map node already have the UV Wrap modifier, so this does apply after the UV Wrap.

Answer (score 9):

I would propose a simpler set-up, pay attention to the highlighted values:

[image]

It basically uses two **Mapping** nodes and one **Vector Math** node. Note that the first mapping node is optional, just for pre-transformation:

Comment: Nice, that looks even cleaner and avoids splitting the coordinates.

Comment: does this work for more than just 4 repeats?

Comment: @GregZaal Right, I admit the current result is not exactly the same one as BI does. I think maddin45 got better point. Btw, do you think it is still possible by following my idea?

Comment: @LeonCheung It doesn't work for me when I'm tiling either by increasing the mapping scale or the UV projection scale :-/

Comment: @AntonioBuch, Yes, like I said to GregZaal, it is not perfect. I'll try to figure it out.