# How to repeat a texture mirrored?

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm using the Blender render, and miss a texture repeat option I know from OpenGL. It is used in one model which has been finished poly-wise, but texture mapping is wrong.

Look at our good old Lakitu friend here, who has obvious texturing issues:
[image]

If you look at the UV mapping on the left, the source to the texturing issue becomes clear: It would be mapped correctly only if the texture would be repeated and mirrored outside its bounds (as if you would use GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT in OpenGL).

However, I do not find such an option in the texture repeat options of the Blender render. Can I only fix this by manually modifying the out-of-bounds UVs (mirroring them back into the texture space and splitting triangles spanning the texture borders)?

Comment: try to delete the incorrect texture part and apply the Mirror Modifier again

Comment: Will using **Mirror** option from [*Image Mapping* scroll](http://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/textures/types/image.html?highlight=image%20mapping#image-mapping) help ? It [may mirror](http://i.imgur.com/QXjXQZ5.jpg) your texture along X, Y or both axes.

Comment: @IgorTatarnikov: That wouldn't be an optimal solution, as the model should stay untouched, and some triangles are not aligned on the middle of the mesh.

Comment: @MrZak:  You're right... it looked like these options were disabled (half-transparent checkboxes), so I didn't click them! That's exactly what I needed. If you make that an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: What Blender version are you referring to for these comments? That link to the Image Mapping documentation is no longer functional - the documentation defaults to version 2.81, and it doesn't seem to be available in version 2.79 either. Blender is not helping its documentation issues by invalidating old links.

Comment: Question and comments are about pre-2.8 and Blender Internal renderer, both legacy now. Not finding any old links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to repeat the texture, at the same time mirroring it, you should check 2 options in the [*Image Mapping* scroll](http://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/textures/types/image.html?highlight=image%20mapping#image-mapping):

1. increase value of the **Repeat** slider to something more, than 1 (otherwise **Mirror** options will continue being disabled, like you've mentioned);
2. check **Mirror X** and / or **Mirror Y** checkboxes.

[image]

The texture will be repeating as the pattern, mirrored on selected axes.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/167035/61043) solved it. You can use the ping-pong node:

[image]

The 'image mapping scroll' from Mr Zak's seems to have disappeared in newer Blender versions.

The downside to this method is that the texture is un-mirrored again if you export, to .FBX for example. If someone knows how to avoid that, please leave a comment or edit this answer...